# How to query firebase database by specific value without knowing the parent key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to find key (ex: `-KYNc6XTtavDtsC-VoqIb`) where email is **amitabh@gmail.com**
I have tried many code, but not working, I am getting full list of data.
this is my code :

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("members");
myRef.orderByChild("email").startAt(emailId).endAt(emailId);
```

---

---

this is what I am getting.

```
DataSnapshot{
  key=members,
  value={
    -KYNYiw5B1d8Brdz5KdR={
      lastname=zxvzxvfsdf44,
      email=fasdfds@rr44,
      firstname=fdafaf44
    },
    -KYNYdX_gZ0tU-AbI1Ab={
      lastname=zxvzxvfsdf,
      email=fasdfds@rr,
      firstname=fdafaf
    },
    -KYNd02QZptRktmR02IH={
      lastname=dfasf,
      email=you@bo.com,
      firstname=amita
    },
    -KYNdlMM4zzlUT9FdSdu={
      lastname=99dfasfs,
      email=99@bos.com,
      firstname=99
    },
    -KYNdBPMqxgSzm1ai92B={
      lastname=dfasfs,
      email=you@bos.com,
      firstname=amitas
    },
    -KYNlYF4OzzCCewJuatt={
      lastname=go2o,
      email=go@to.to,
      firstname=go
    },
    -KYNo7ZvLQeCGm97yUvf={
      lastname=bamio,
      email=samio@ss.com,
      firstname=amio
    },
    -KYNdBRAipnlTYCCUwz6={
      lastname=dfasfs,
      email=you@bos.com,
      firstname=amitas
    },
    -KYNc6XTtavDtsC-VoqI={
      lastname=Sarkar,
      email=amitabh@gmail.com,
      firstname=amitabh
    },
    -KYNcHdlZjUlNSsjKlyW={
      lastname=gjaldga,
      email=ee@ee.com,
      firstname=ami
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
myRef.orderByChild("email").startAt(emailId).endAt(emailId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        Log.e("onChildAdded", dataSnapshot.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found the solution. You can simplify the query in this case to `myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailId)`